# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when adding a sheet to Excel workbook

Tags: vb.net, excel

When i'm trying to save my datagridview component to excel i got an error

`Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

around this line: `xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add("[Sheet1]")`

There is the part of my code:

```
    Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer


    xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add("[Sheet1]")


    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value
            Next
        Next
    Next

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("c:\users\500998877\documents\bg\dtgv1.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    Process.Start("c:\users\500998877\documents\bg\dtgv1.xlsx")
```

Comment: Ok, Look up what type of parameters are expected for the [`Worksheets.Add()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838966(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: i'm new in vb anyway, can't realize what should i add to 
`xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add("Sheet1",  ,  ,)`

Comment: i don't know why should i add more paramter, coz the default values are goods

Comment: The problem is that you are passing a String name of `"Sheet1"` rather than an object of `Sheet` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but try the following:

```
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add
xlWorksheet.Name = "MyNewSheet"
```

Be aware that there may also be a default "Sheet1" with a defaut instance of Excel.

You may wish to start your research with [this MSDN reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.add.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it work !  :) 
Anyway i find an other way like this:
`xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
            xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add()`