# Error hresult 0x800a03ec trying to assign value to excel cell

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I'm trying to export the content of a DataGridView to an excel worksheet by using the below code

```
Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Dim xlSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlBook.Sheets(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
xlSheet.Name = "MySheet"
xlApp.Visible = True
With xlSheet
    For C As Integer = 0 To DGV_IntCalc.Columns.Count - 1
        .Range(.Cells(1, C + 1)).Value = DGV_IntCalc.Columns(C).HeaderText
        For R As Integer = 0 To DGV_IntCalc.RowCount - 1
            .Range(.Cells(R + 2, C + 1)).Value = DGV_IntCalc.Rows(R).Cells(C).Value
        Next
    Next
End With
```

I get error on `.Range(.Cells(1, C + 1)).Value = DGV_IntCalc.Columns(C).HeaderText`

I have `Option Strict On` so I can't use  `.Cells(1, C + 1).Value = DGV_IntCalc.Columns(C).HeaderText` because of the late binding

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I think you need `.Range(.Cells(1, C + 1)).Value = DGV_IntCalc.Columns(C+1).HeaderText`, because when `C=0`, what is `Columns(0)`?

Comment: @BruceWayne I checked the value of `DGV_IntCalc.Columns(C).HeaderText` and it is a string containing the Header Text of the first column of the DGV. The problem must be in the first part of the row: `.Range(.Cells(1, C + 1)).Value =`

Comment: For troubleshooting, just make that `.Range(.Cells(1,1)).Value` and see if it still throws an error.

Comment: @BruceWayne Done, I still get the same error

Comment: Couple more debug thoughts - change `With xlSheet` to the VB.net equivalent of `Sheets("MySheet")`.  If that doesn't work, try removing the "anchor" to `With xlSheet` and just let it run on the active sheet.  Also, I don't see where `SGV_IntCalc` is set, or is that a VB.net thing that doesn't need to be declared or anything?  Also, how "big" is the header text, in characters? There's a limit of 1024 characters for a cell I believe. Also, does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28063502/4650297) help?

Comment: @BruceWayne I found the bug. I'll post it as an aswer.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the range has only one cell, you need to insert both starting and ending cells of the range.

The solution is to change:

```
.Range(.Cells(1, C + 1)).Value = DGV_IntCalc.Columns(C).HeaderText
```

with:

```
.Range(.Cells(1, C + 1), .Cells(1, C + 1)).Value = DGV_IntCalc.Columns(C).HeaderText
```

Comment: YES. How didn't I catch that? It's usually the first thing I check for. Nice call :D